# Mark duplicates when using Rank()

Tags: sql-server, database

I am getting a ranked list exactly how I want to using:

`SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) as rank, name, score FROM players`

Is there a way to mark duplicate ranks in SQL?

For example, from this:

```
rank  name  score
----  ----  -----
 1     bob    98
 2     tom    96
 2     guy    96
 4     lou    92
```

to this

```
rank  name  score
----  ----  -----
 1     bob    98
 T2    tom    96
 T2    guy    96
 4     lou    92
```

Comment: Sure, but which one would you want to 'mark' as a duplicate (or would both be 'marked')?

Comment: The rows with similar rankings. I will update the question

Comment: Something like `[rank] = CASE WHEN COUNT(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY Score) > 1 THEN 'T' + CAST(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score) AS VARCHAR(255)) ELSE CAST(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score) AS VARCHAR(255)) END` would work for your desired output.

Comment: @ZLK That's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
with q as
(
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) as rank, 
name, score 
FROM players
)
select *, count(*) over (partition by rank) players_at_rank
from q

rank                 name                 score       players_at_rank
-------------------- -------------------- ----------- ---------------
1                    alex                 2           1
2                    fred                 5           2
2                    joe                  5           2
4                    sue                  9           1

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will mark all duplicate ranks. It checks whether the previous or subsequent entry has the same value.

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) as rank, name, score,
  IIF(LAG(score,1) OVER (ORDER BY score) = score OR LEAD(score,1) OVER (ORDER BY score) = score,1,0) as IsDuplicate
FROM players
```